# How to edit mp3 tags using regular expressions?

Tags: mp3

I have a long list of mp3 files which not acceptable **tags**. I need to be able to change tags of mp3 files using regular expressions. For example, there are files with following `titles`:

```
Title
-----
abc_01
abc_02
abc_03 

___
Should be like:

Title
------
smth_001
smth_002
smth_003
```

How can I accomplish this? I am running Windows 7.

Comment: What OS do you have?

Comment: I am using Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you try with [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/advanced.htm#tutorial_rename)s "Multi-Rename tool" or [MultiRenamer](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/File-Management/Ahisical-MultiRenamer.shtml) for batch.
For tags, try [MP3Tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/)

[image: MP3 Tag actions]

Comment: More details please. So far I managed only to rename mp3 file but not **change mp3 tag**. (using Total Commander)

Comment: Try mp3tag I think it can do multi conversions and actions

Comment: mp3 tag will do tag -> filename, filename to tag, and doing changes using regex under 'actions' I believe

Comment: yes, like examples on image